# Convert values in a single column in pyspark dataframe to lowercase in text cleanup using lower function

Tags: python, pyspark

Trying to convert convert values in a pyspark dataframe single column to lowercase for the text cleanup using .lower function

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
f.lower(f.col(col("subject")).show()
```

Getting:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is a parenthesis and also you only need to use f.col() once.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
f.lower(f.col("subject")).show()
```

You need to assign it to your dataframe:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = df.withColumn("subject",f.lower(f.col("subject")))
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`show` is a method for dataframes.

let's assume your dataframe is `df`, you can do :

```
df.withColumn(
    "subject", 
    F.lower(F.col("subject"))
).show()
```